# Access SQL Server via StaticIP( from outside and access it locally(Intranet) as well

Tags: sql-server

I want to access SQL server via an application (it is a desktop application) which is installed on remote location, where as SQL server installed in Main Office, where other applications are also accessing same SQL server on LAN.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: definitely possible first link from google http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically this is not problem. Once installed, SQL Server will react both on the internal IP and external - if the Firewall is configured to forward SQL-Server Traffic (TCP 1433).

BUT - from security point it's not a good idea to expose your SQL Server directly to the internet. In the past there have been several security problems that would have exposed more than you wanted to expose. I would suggest external users, not inside your LAN use a VPN Connection to get inside your internal Network. I work every day over VPN with SQL Server and it's stable and secure.

Comment: "Firewall is configured to forward SQL-Server Traffic" --- I'm sure you misused `forward` term in this case

Comment: in specifig I mean "port forwarding" - "Port forwarding allows remote computers (for example, computers on the Internet) to connect to a specific computer or service within a private local-area network" (LAN).[3]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding - why do you think it's misused?

Comment: because sql server might already have a white IP address. In that case its firewall doesn't need to forward packets.

Comment: @zerkms your router needs to forward connection to the machine where sql server is installed.

Comment: if you really want to use remote sql-server connection. at least change the TCP/IP port to something other than 1433 and disable `sa` account. this may keep you safe from most of the lazy/DOS attacks.

Comment: @bansi: you're making an assumption about OP's network structure. 1. You cannot know how it's organized 2. It's not a programming question

Comment: @zerkms I agree with you. It's not a programming question.